# How couchbase ensures uniqueness of id?

Tags: indexing, couchbase, sql++

As per the [documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/services-and-indexes/indexes/indexing-and-query-perf.html#primary-index) primary index (index on document key) is optional in Couchbase. How does Couchbase efficiently ensure uniqueness of document key without an index?

Answer (score 1):

The primary index that documentation refers to is only for N1QL queries, and has nothing to do with enforcing uniqueness.

Instead, uniqueness is enforced by the key/value data service. From the ["Data" overview documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/data/data.html#keys):

> Each value (binary or JSON) is identified by a unique key, defined by
>   the user or application when the item is saved. The key is immutable:
>   once the item is saved, the key cannot be changed.

I am not an expert on Couchbase internals, but unique keys are fundamental to how Couchbase stores/retrieves/shards data. Check out [Understanding vBuckets](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/vbuckets.html) for more information ('vBucket' is analogous to 'shard'). Here's a snippet:

> Items are written to and retrieved from vBuckets by means of a CRC32
>   hashing algorithm, which is applied to the item’s key, and so produces
>   the number of the vBucket in which the item resides.